# PCIe link speed limit in dmesg when hot reset "PCIe 8.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x4 link at 0000:02:02.0"

Tags: drivers, ssd, nvme, pcie

When we do PCIe hot reset and meet below log in dmesg.
The PCIe device is PCIe gen4x4 NVME SSD.

duplicate step:

1. power on, gen4x4
2. PCIe hot reset,
3. relink up, found PCIe link in gen1x4, with dmesg show limited BW.

Platform information:

- OS:Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel version 5.15)
- CPU:AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
- MB:X570GT8

`dmesg` output:

```
[16:53:30 2024] pci 0000:03:00.0: 8.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x4 link at 0000:02:02.0 (capable of 63.012 Gb/s with 16.0 GT/s PCIe x4 link
[16:53:30 2024] pci 0000:03:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xf7700000-0xf770ffff pref]
[16:53:30 2024] pci 0000:03:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xf7710000-0xf7713fff 64bit]
[16:53:30 2024] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:03:00.0
```

`lspci` information:

```
LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x4, ASPM not supported
ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (downgraded), Width x4 (ok)
```

Is there any idea to find out why the link speed has been reduced? (hw issue/Driver setting)

Comment: Does the link speed work properly if you echo to /remove, wait a while, then reprobe for PCI devices to readd it.?

Comment: NO~rescan not help.